# Fill the screen in 6502asm.com

Tags: graphical-output, assembly

## Introduction

I've always liked the idea of finding the most possible bang-for-your-buck squeezed out of a tiny chip, like the 6502. Of course, I'll need to start small. Filling the screen on 6502asm.com should be easy enough.

## Challenge

Fill the entire program output screen on 6502asm.com with the color white using the least amount of unique executed bytes as possible. Or, set every memory space between 0x0200 and 0x05FF with any byte whose lower nybble is 1.

No self modifying code. (executing bytes that were changed after being assembled)
Try to keep the memory changed to a minimum, don't go changing bytes willy-nilly.

Comment: I don't think "No self modifying code" and "unique executed bytes" are necessary, and they aren't even objective. If you remove these, you can add the [tag:code-golf] tag.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:

```
lda #1
ldx #$02

fill_screen:
stx $01

draw_segment:
sta ($00),Y
iny
bne draw_segment

inx
cpx #$06
bne fill_screen
```

And as hex:

```
0600: a901 a202 8601 9100 c8d0 fbe8 e006 d0f4
```

That's exactly 16 bytes of memory used as code, with 2 external bytes used as program storage.

Comment: If you started with X=5 and went down to 1, you could TXA instead of LDA #1, to save a byte.